# Flask + SQLAlchemy OperationalError

Tags: python, docker, flask, sqlalchemy, newrelic

I am trying to play around with deploying Flask application. When I run the code using docker swarm on Amazon's EC2 I started to get following errors:

Error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc:OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.[SQL: SELECT visitor."ID" AS "visitor_ID", visitor.username AS visitor_username, visitor.visits AS visitor_visits FROM visitor](Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 202, in run
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 545, in manage_workers
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 616, in spawn_workers
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 140, in init_process
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 123, in run
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 67, in run_for_one
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 29, in accept
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 134, in handle
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 175, in handle_request
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/newrelic/api/wsgi_application.py", line 665, in _nr_wsgi_application_wrapper_
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/newrelic/api/wsgi_application.py", line 193, in __init__
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/newrelic/api/wsgi_application.py", line 555, in _nr_wsgi_application_wrapper_
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/framework_flask.py", line 45, in _nr_wrapper_handler_
File "/app/src/views.py", line 5, in index
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3233, in all
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3389, in __iter__
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3414, in _execute_and_instances
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1250, in _execute_context
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1246, in _execute_context
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 588, in do_execute
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/database_psycopg2.py", line 51, in execute
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/database_dbapi2.py", line 25, in execute
```

Initially I thought that this might be a result of not closing db connections after using them, but when I added `db.session.close()` the error still occurs.

Full code can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/gonczor/aws-simple-app), the most important parts are:

views.py file:

```
from models import Visitor, db


def index():
    visitors = Visitor.query.all()
    response = [
        {"id": visitor.ID, "username": visitor.username, "visits": visitor.visits}
        for visitor in visitors
    ]
    db.session.close()
    return {"results": response}


def increment_visits(username: str) -> dict:
    if username == "favicon.ico":
        return {}
    visitor = Visitor.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if visitor is None:
        visitor = Visitor(username=username, visits=1)
        db.session.add(visitor)
    else:
        visitor.visits += 1
    db.session.commit()
    return {"id": visitor.ID, "username": visitor.username, "visits": visitor.visits}
```

main.py file:

```
import sys

from flask import Flask

from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, HOST, PORT, DEBUG, DB_POOL_SIZE
from models import db


def make_app() -> Flask:
    flask_app = Flask(__name__)
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = DB_POOL_SIZE
    add_urls(flask_app)
    db.init_app(app=flask_app)
    return flask_app


def add_urls(flask_app: Flask):
    from views import index, increment_visits
    flask_app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=index)
    flask_app.add_url_rule('/<username>/', view_func=increment_visits)


app = make_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if 'createdb' in sys.argv:
        app.app_context().push()
        db.create_all()
    else:
        app.run(host=HOST, port=PORT, debug=DEBUG)
```

models.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()


class Visitor(db.Model):
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    visits = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=1)
```

Docker services:

```
ubuntu@srv1:~$ docker stack ps --filter "desired-state=running" demo
ID                  NAME                IMAGE                               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE         ERROR               PORTS
frbdra27cdcb        demo_web.1          gonczor/aws-simple-app:prod         srv1                Running             Running 7 hours ago
0by6yhvr9n4a        demo_nginx.1        gonczor/aws-simple-app-nginx:prod   srv1                Running             Running 3 days ago
ym2t3we6r5b1        demo_db.1           postgres:11                         srv1                Running             Running 4 days ago
luwgpr3jnsj8        demo_web.2          gonczor/aws-simple-app:prod         srv1                Running             Running 7 hours ago
```

I have no clue where this error might come from, so I am happy to provide any further details.

**EDIT**

Output of requested command:

```
simple_app=# SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database;
 sum
-----
   2
(1 row)
```

Comment: The actual exception may be helpful. Are your models setup to be used like `Visitor.query...` or should they be used like `db.session.query(Visitor)...`?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the traceback is missing the actual exception (last line snipped off?)

Comment: @djnzI I've added the actual error message, models configuration. I've tried to perform the query based on those docs: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Comment: Is is possible that PSQL terminates query due to excesive connection number. Please post a result of `SELECT sum(numbackends) FROM pg_stat_database`.

Comment: Just for curiosity, please change to `workers = 1` in `gunicorn_conf.py`.

Comment: I did it and deployed. Also I scaled down the number of web services to 1. I have 7 connections, but the error occurred once so far.

Comment: You can also try to bump `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE` a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, though I have very vague why it works. I found an answer in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/2vbphd/flasksqlalchemy_closing_the_session/cogyz27/), so here we go.

The error mainly occurred after a long idleness. When I was flooding the app with requests during benchmarking nothing happened. It seems that some connections were kept by SQLAlchemy for too long. I lowered the POOL_RECYCLE_TIME to 10 minutes and updated the settings format to avoid deprecation that will be introduced in version 3.0 of Flask-SQLAlchemy.

```
DB_POOL_SIZE = int(os.environ.get('DB_POOL_SIZE', '10'))
DB_POOL_RECYCLE = int(os.environ.get('DB_POOL_RECYCLE', '60'))
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {
    'pool_size': DB_POOL_SIZE,
    'pool_recycle': DB_POOL_RECYCLE,
}
```

As I say, I don't fully understand why this was a problem, but after introducing those changes no errors occurred. Anyway comments and links to materials explaining this issue are welcome.